# Handle ImageView size on screen rotation

Tags: android

This is not much of a problem but a requirement of an application I'm working on. I have an activity and a fragment inside that activity. This is the layout of a fragment:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 tools:context=".NavigationActivity"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avaImage"
            android:layout_width="687dp"
            android:layout_height="438dp"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txtLabel"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Available"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm including a drawable resource as the `imageView`'s `src` programatically.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.avaImage);
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.availability_green));
```

The image works pretty nicely in a portrait orientation but in landscape, the image is shrunk. 
So, my question is, is there any way to control how much the image would shrink on screen rotation making sure it'd show the same way across Android devices?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to specify how your image will handle size changes. This two properties will keep the original aspect ratio:

CENTER_INSIDE
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

CENTER_CROP
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Comment: Let me try that. But, is there no other way to specify just how much an image should be scaled on screen rotation?

Comment: Yes, you can use [android:maxHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getMaxHeight()) and [android:maxWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getMaxWidth()) @BasitSaeed

Comment: Should I use set it programmatically or should I just declare it in the layout file?

Comment: Tried it but the result was same.

Comment: But you have both max and scaletype properties in the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged( Configuration newConfig)
 {
   super.onConfigurationChanged( newConfig);
   SCREEN_WIDTH  = contextApplication.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
   SCREEN_HEIGHT = contextApplication.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
   if( SCREEN_WIDTH < SCREEN_HEIGHT) // portret
     {
       image.setAdjustViewBounds( true);
       image.setScaleType( ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
       image.setMaxWidth( 10);
       image.setMinimumWidth( 10);
       image.setMaxHeight( 10);
       image.setMinimumHeight( 10);
     }
    else // land or square (if this is exist :) )
     {
       image.setAdjustViewBounds( true);
       image.setScaleType( ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
       image.setMaxWidth( 20);
       image.setMinimumWidth( 20);
       image.setMaxHeight( 20);
       image.setMinimumHeight( 20);
     }
 }
```

And add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to activity in AndroidMainfest

Comment: Nop! That didn't do it!